# Bit manipulation on character string

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, xor

Can we apply bit manipulation on a character string?
If so, is it always possible to retrieve back a character string from the manipulated string?

I was hoping to use the XOR operator on two strings by converting them to binary and then back to *character string*.

I took up some code from another StackOverflow question but it only solves half the problem

```
std::string TextToBinaryString(string words) 
{
string binaryString = "";
for (char& _char : words) 
    {
        binaryString +=std::bitset<8>(_char).to_string();
    }
return binaryString;
}
```

I don't know how to convert this string of ones and zeroes back to a string of characters.
I did read *std::stio* in some google search results as a solution but was not able to understand them.

The manipulation that I wish to do is

```
std::string message("Hello World");
int n = message.size();
bin_string = TextToBinaryString(message)

std::string left,right;
bin_string.copy(left,n/2,0);
bin_string.copy(right,n,n/2);

std::string result = left^right;
```

I know I can hardcode this by picking up every entry and applying the operation but it is the conversion of the binary string back to characters that are making me scratch my head.

> *EDIT: *I am trying to implement a cipher framework called Feistel cipher (*SORRY, should had made that clear before*) there they use the property of XOR that when you XOR something with the same thing again it cancels out... For eg. (A^B)^B=A. I wanted to output the ciphered jibberish in the middle. Hence, the query.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting them to binary and back"? What did you try? Please provide a minimal example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: What kind of bit manipulation do you want to perform? What results do you expect after that manipulation?

Comment: Its C++ you can XOR a Window if you want to!  Your question doesn't make it obvious what you want to do and what you expect as the result, please can you edit it and then people can help more.

Comment: _Can we apply bit manipulation on a character string?_ Yes. _If so, is it always possible to retrieve back a character string from the manipulated string?_: it depends on the manipulation that has beeon donw. _So far no luck_ : no luck with what? You should read this: [ask] and then [edit]  your question accordingly.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen As mentioned in the question, I was trying to use the XOR operator. I am trying my hand at building a basic cipher framework but am not quite experienced with bit manipulation using c++.

Comment: @Jabberwockey I am sorry for not specifying the details of my query, I will be more descriptive from now onwards

Comment: @NSR now it's better, but a [mcve] would be even better.

Comment: `string[0] ^= 123` just works, what's the problem?

Comment: @NSR you showd the code that transforms your text into a string of 1s and 0s that represent the ASCII values of s string in binary. But you're not bit manipulating anything here.

Comment: Have you looked at the interface of [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) to see if it offers a suitable conversion already? Better yet, have you thought about why you want to XOR a string of 1,0 characters instead if just XORing the raw character values?

Comment: @NSR Forget about strings. You are not dealing with any string at all. You are dealing with bytes of data. You read some bytes of data, work on those bytes of data and they do not have any meaningful representation. You could use `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` to store that input. It's a series of 8-bit numbers, and on each of these numbers you can perform bit manipulations of your choice.

Comment: @NSR it would be great if you could show your code as [mcve].

Comment: @NSR OK, it seems you want to take the first half of the string and XOR it with the second half of the string. Well in that case the operation is not reversible. What makes you think it is?

Comment: Well, it's reversible if you then want to keep one half of the string as a "key" to "decrypt" the other half again later ... (I use both terms loosely). I still don't understand the fixation on "binary-looking strings", or what you want the result to look like, or what you expect to do with that result.

Comment: @Jabberwocky As I said I was trying to implement a cipher framework called Feistel cipher (I think you know a lot about the topic..... I am a noob here) there they use the property of XOR that when you XOR something with the same thing again it cancels out... For eg. (A^B)^B=A. I wanted to output the ciphered jibberish in the middle.

Comment: @NSR you're mentioning _Feistel cipher_ for the first time in your last comment.... I think you should take [edit] your question and put all relevent information _there_. From that last comment my answer should probably be the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we apply bit manipulation on a character string?

Yes.

A character is an integer type, so you can do anything to them you can do to any other integer. *What happened when you tried*?

> If so, is it always possible to retrieve back a character string from the manipulated string?

No. It is *sometimes* possible to recover the original string, but some manipulations are not reversible.

XOR, the particular operation you asked about, is self-reversing, so it works in that case but not in general.

A cheesy example (depends on ASCII character set, don't do this in real code for converting case, etc. etc.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s("a");
    std::cout << "original: " << s << '\n';
    s[0] ^= 0x20;
    std::cout << "modified: " << s << '\n';
    s[0] ^= 0x20;
    std::cout << "restored: " << s << '\n';
}
```

shows (on an ASCII-compatible) system

```
original: a
modified: A
restored: a
```

Note that I'm not converting "a" into "1100001" first, and then using XOR (somehow) zero bit 5 giving "1000001" and then converting that back into "A". Why would I?

This part of your question suggests you don't understand the difference between values and representations: the character is *always* stored in binary. You can *also* always treat it as if it is stored in octal, or in decimal, or in hexadecimal - the choice of base only affects how we write (or print) the value, and not what the value is in itself.

---

Writing a Feistel cipher where the plaintext and key are the same length is trivial:

```
std::string feistel(std::string const &text, std::string const &key)
{
    std::string result;
    std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), key.begin(),
                   std::back_inserter(result),
                   [](char a, char b) { return a^b; }
                   );
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't work at all if the key is shorter, though - looping round the key appropriately is left as an exercise for the reader.

Oh, and printing the encoded string is unlikely to work nicely (unless your key is helpfully just a sequence of space characters, as above).

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain a little more about how this problem of the key size and message length is solved when these are applied to actual existing ciphers? Pointing out any useful resources on the net will also be very helpful. P.S.: I am really sorry for the improper formatting of my query earlier.

Comment: Don't worry about apologising, just do better next time :-)  It's always hard to frame a good question in an area you don't know well, and you'll get better with effort and practice. Anyway, you can just search for "Feistel cipher", but try thinking about what a reasonable solution is and try it. Code is free, practice is valuable, and wasted effort often isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include<string>
#include<cassert>

using namespace std;

std::string someBitmanipulation(string words)
{
  std::string manipulatedstring;

  for (char& thechar : words)
  {
    thechar ^= 0x5A;  // xor with 0x5A
  }
  return manipulatedstring;
}

int main()
{
  std::string original{ "ABC" };
  // xor each char of original with 0x5a at put result into manipulated
  auto manipulated = someBitmanipulation(original);

  // check if manipulating the manipulated string is the same as the original string
  assert(original == someBitmanipulation(manipulated));
}
```

You don't need `std::bitset` at all.

Now change `thechar ^= 0x5A;`  to say `thechar |= 0x5A;` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to output the manipulated string as well as the string produced after manipulating the manipulated string but there was no output on the console. Although, the equality operator did return zero............... I used _std::cout_ for tthis.

Comment: @NSR your manipulated string probably contains unprintable characters. Don't use `cout` but output the hexadecimal code of each char.